# Mapped Network Drive, File.Exists Strange behaviour

Tags: c#, .net

I am facing following strange problem.

- Steps

  1. Mapped one network drive as Y:\, It has file Y:\Abc.txt
  2. .Net application stores the file path in Database as "Y:\Abc.txt"
  3. Disconnect the drive. [ Note: My application is still running at this time]
  4. Application read the path from DB, and use File.Exists method of .net for "Y:\Abc.txt"
  5. Even if drive is disconnected still File.Exists returns true and File.ReadAllLines to get all data in file is working.

---

> > NOTE:
>
> If I close the application after step-3, then it gives proper error,
>   like file not exists.

Does anyone here faced this issue.

Comment: Do you disconnect the drive using the same user account as the one used for executing the application?

Comment: Almost certainly but, I doubt that is actually your question. What is your question?

Comment: what system? I can't reproduce it on Windows7 + .Net4.0

Comment: Windows 7, Question is even if file not exists how File.Exists is working ?

Answer (score 2):

When you unmap the drive, you do NOT unmap it for pre-existing processes: your process started when it was mapped, and so it keeps seeing it.

(This is only true for mapped drive; if it was e.g. a USB drive and you physically removed it, then of course your program would no longer be able access it.)

In short, this is how things work!

Comment: Got it, so is there any solution apart from restarting my process.  Is there any alternative rather to Disconnect drive.

Comment: @simon, not sure about this, as soon as I disconnect the drive, `File.Exists` shows `False` for me

Comment: May you can use FileInfo and `Refresh()` the instance.

Comment: @Bolu - I'm doing some testing myself!

Comment: I'm getting the same: it goes when I disconnect it. @Banng - was the program running as a different user?

Comment: Use the UNC path instead of the drive letter; then you won't be affected by someone disconnecting it.

Comment: @simonatrcl: User is Administrator all the time.